# Flink Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh

Tags: apache-flink

This is the first time I use flink, after I downloaded https://dlcdn.apache.org/flink/flink-1.16.0/flink-1.16.0-bin-scala_2.12.tgz from the website and unzip it, I run this command to start it   ./bin/start-cluster.sh , however when I want to look Flink UI on  http://localhost:8081/ , an error occurred "Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh."

I looked up the internet, and maybe there are two possible reasons.

1. I have started multiple flink clusters, and I should clean up all the flink processes, but when I use this command   ps aux | grep flink  , I don't find multiple processes, just two.
2. The problem is from the zookeeper, but I don't know how to solve it.

the directory structure is as follow, does anyone know which part should I change?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjPsU.png)

java11  macos M1

I'd appreciate it if someone replied.

I want to see the Flink UI, but now when I go to http://localhost:8081/ , I can only get a message "Service temporarily unavailable due to an ongoing leader election. Please refresh".

Answer (score 1):

This is not a flink related question, the problem is the hostname, write HOST="localhost" to ~.bash_profile and reload it using source ~/.bash_profile in the command line.